# Excel VBA conditional format sets successfully, but not active until applied manually

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I created a simple macro for a formula based conditional formatting. When I run the macro, the conditional formatting doesn't apply. However, when I go to the manage rules window, I find that the rule is applied and if I click on edit rule and simply click OK without making any changes to the formula or other conditions, the conditional formatting is applied. I am confused, if everything is fine, then why the formatting is not being applied automatically after executing the macro?

```
Sub April3()
' ' April3 Macro ' '

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition

    Set rg = Range("K4:Q8")
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=OR(K4=$B$2:$D$32)")
    With cond1.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please attache your existing code. There is no way for anyone to help other than offering generic suggestions to try, unless they can actually see what your code is doing.

Comment: Sub April3()
'
' April3 Macro
'

'
Dim rg As Range
Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, 
Set rg = Range("K4:Q8")

rg.FormatConditions.Delete

Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=OR(K4=$B$2:$D$32)")


    With cond1.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    
   
    
End Sub

Comment: I tested the code in a new workbook, and it worked for me. I have Excel 2016. Which version do you have? Have you tried adding this code to the code module of a new workbook, and testing it there?

Comment: The problem here is that your conditional format formula needs to be calculated as an array formula, which is why it doesn't calculate properly until you go in and do it manually.  Change your conditional format formula to this instead so it doesn't require array calculation: `=COUNTIF($B$2:$D$32,K4)`

Comment: This is an actual known problem with VBA setting conditional format formulas.  I have edited the post to make the title more meaningful and also posted an answer that will help future viewers.  I have upvoted the question to try to offset the unnecessary downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your conditional format formula requires array calculation which VBA can't specify.  This is the reason that the conditional format rule gets applied, but doesn't do anything until you manually go into the conditional format rule and click OK.

To get around this, change your conditional format formula so that it doesn't require array calculation:

```
Sub April3()
' ' April3 Macro ' '

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition

    Set rg = Range("K4:Q8")
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=COUNTIF($B$2:$D$32,K4)")
    With cond1.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that the formula is now a COUNTIF instead of an OR.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. This helped.